# Error in stl_algo.h, comparing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, compare

I'm trying to find out if an object is exists within a vector of pointers.

```
vector<Objectoid*> elements;

bool contains(Objectoid &o){
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        if(elements[i] == &o){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but get these errors,

```
no match for 'operator==' in '__first. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Objectoid**, _Container = std::vector<Objectoid*, std::allocator<Objectoid*> >]() == __value'
```

in `stl_algo.h`.

Help much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Full code

```
class Cell : public Element{

public:
    Rectf cellRect;
    Vec2i size;
    Vec2i pos;
    vector<Objectoid*> elements;

    Cell(Vec2f &pos_, Vec2f &size_){
        pos = pos_;
        size = size_;
        Vec2f p2 = Vec2f(pos.x + size.x, pos.y + size.y);
        cellRect = Rectf(pos, p2);
    }

    void add(Objectoid &o){
        elements.push_back(&o);
    }
    void remove(Objectoid &o){
        elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), o), elements.end());
    }

    bool contains(Objectoid &o){
        for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
            if(elements[i] == &o){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

I'm trying to implement a hash table for collision detection in a 2D game. This is the class for each cell of the table.

**EDIT**

So the culprit is actually

```
void remove(Objectoid &o){
    elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), o), elements.end());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the culprit code? The error message is complaining about `operator*`, but there are no uses of `operator*` in this code.

Comment: Also, signed/unsigned mismatch between `i` and `std::vector<t, alloc>::size()`.

Comment: I just compiled this code (plus the three lines `#include <vector>`, `using std::vector;`, `struct Objectoid;` at the top) and the only complaint I get from the compiler is the signed/unsigned mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a comment:** It is helpful that you've now provided something that we can compile. That being said, there's a pile of code that you've presented that isn't part of the problem (your constructor for example), and we can't actually compile the code you've presented (`Vec2i` has no definition).

**Second, an answer to your problem:** Clang provides the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:208:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Objectoid *' and 'const Objectoid')
      if (*__first == __val)

sa.cc:27:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::remove<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Objectoid **, std::vector<Objectoid *, std::allocator<Objectoid *> > >, Objectoid>' requested here
      elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), o), elements.end());
```

If I change that line to:

```
elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), &o), elements.end());
```

Then everything compiles. The version I've provided compiles, because the third argument of std::remove needs to be the `value_type` of whatever you're iterating over. You originally provided a `Objectoid`, but we need it to be the `value_type` of your container, which is a `Objectoid *`.

---

And just for the sake of expanding on the first note, a good simplified problem statement, could include code that looks like the following. It's extremely small, and the problem is still apparent. Anyone who comes across this, would be able to help very quickly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Objectoid {};

int main() {
    std::vector<Objectoid *> elements;
    Objectoid o;

    elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), o), elements.end());
}
```

Comment: Addendum: There's not enough code here to know for sure, but it is *very likely* that your use of `vector<Objectoid*>` is a gun loaded and waiting to shoot you in the foot.  If a `Cell` object ever outlives the `Objectoid`s that it holds unmanaged pointers to, the gun will go off.  You may want to take a hard look at `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @jossgray: To try and clarify my tone, I don't mean any of this as anything mean. It's simply to help you get answers quickly to your issues. That being said, I've found that when I have an issue, preparing the small, self-contained code that produces the error, often helps me fix the problem (and more fully understand the diagnostic that the compiler informs us of).

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense because the compiler is complaining about `operator*`, yet there are no uses of that in your example.

In the mean time, you should use STL algorithms and rewrite your `contains` as:

```
bool contains(Objectoid &o) {
    return std::find(elements.cbegin(), elements.cend(), &o) != elements.cend();
}
```

which completely avoids the problem.